# Is it possible to write to a mmap'd file without getting a bus error

Tags: c++, c, mmap

I'm trying to monitor a file that I create for when the contents change from `0` to `1`. This code create the file and maps it fine, I then spin, waiting for the contents of `*map` to change from `'0'` to `'1'`.

However as soon as I run `echo 1 > file.dat` the code crashes with a `Bus Error`.

I am assuming this is because a new file is being created by echo (or anything else I try) and the mmap is no longer pointing to something relevant. Is there any way to make this work?

```
int fd = open(filename.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);

write(fd, "0", 1)

char* map = static_cast<char*>(mmap(0, 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
```

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: lol "emotional"??

Comment: Well, I guess it is reflecting the effort spent :)

Comment: Could you please at least setup a sample at e.g. [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You can catch SIGBUS and recheck until it succeed...

Comment: I could write it to be more emotional if you like, "woe has befallen me, my mmap, it crashes with much aplomb, whatever shall I do? Lend me your neurons on this day!"

Comment: Thanks @yngum I will either do that or do what is suggested below with `dd`

Comment: @Salgar: You could also just repeatedly `getc` and `rewind` the file instead of memory mapping. That's probably actually more efficient if the file is only one byte long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo 1 > the_file` does the following:

1. Truncate `the_file` to 0 bytes.
2. Append the characters `1` and `\n` to `the_file`

In between steps 1 and 2, the file has length 0.

(Step 1 is performed by the shell, when it interprets the redirection `>the_file`. Step 2 is then performed by the `echo` command, so there could be a significant amount of time between the two.)

If you want to overwrite one character of the file, you can use `dd`:

```
echo 1 | dd of=the_file bs=1 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

Comment: Well, the question doesn't seem to be linux specific, or is it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, it will be the same on any posix system. Why?

Comment: Because `dd` isn't available on every posix compliant system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: According to Posix (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html), it was added in Issue 2. That was quite a long time ago.

Comment: I know that windows isn't really posix compliant, but when I type `dd` at a `cmd` prompt, it says _"The "dd" command is either misspelled or
could not be found."_. I've upvoted your answer anyway, just nitpicking ;-) ... Not sure if MSys would support `dd` (I've got it installed on my system).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: From the words "bus error", I'm guessing that the target system is actually Mac OS X. The dd manpage here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dd.1.html is dated 1994. And, no, Windows `cmd` is not even vaguely Posix. I don't have a windows system handy, but it would surprise me if MSys doesn't support dd. Even busybox has dd.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was referring to Linux, apologies. How is this usually done out of interest, as there are many files in /proc/... That you can modify by echoing 1 or 0 or some other number to them and they dont cause the kernel to error

Comment: @salgar: "Files" in `/proc` aren't really files. They are kernel functions which implement (some of) the file operations. Most `/proc/...` files cannot be truncated, so the `trunc` call done by the shell (silently) fails.